# <div> should only be clickable when logged in. Best practice?

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm developing the frontend for a website using Laravel as php-framework. I have an area with a few clickable divs, which, if logged in should redirect you to another page, and if not display a tooltip telling the user to log in first.

The tooltip is shown with jquery, like so:

```
$(".flip-container").click(function(){
    $("div.login li .tooltip").fadeIn(200);
});

$(".flip-container .back").mouseout(function(){
    $("div.login li .tooltip").fadeOut(200);    
});
```

Now, when the user is logged in, this obviously should not happen, and .flip-container should have a link around it. I just use the laravel Auth:check method to check if the user is logged in or not:

```
@if (Auth::check())
```

So how do I stop the jquery from running if the user is logged in? Do I have to give .flip-container another name and assign the same css to it or is there another better way to do it? I don't want the user to just go into the inspector and just change the class..

Comment: What if your user does not have javascript? You can check the user status with php, and dont sent the javascript is the user is not logge in.

Comment: I must be underthinking this... Why not a simple <?php if() {}?> statement around either where the onclick occurs, or even around the whole element? A $_SESSION[''] variable might do the trick for you as well, though I don't know how that aligns with best practices...

Comment: Yes, that would work if I had the onclick in the html, but the click is defined in the script file, and I can't do the check there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to separate the JS that does the tooltips into some file, and don't include that file if the user is logged in.

Comment: Yeah, that should be a neat way to do it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a logged-in class to the .flip-container div in PHP. Then in jQuery check to see if it has the class .logged-in and go from there.